# pgrep -f exits with 1

Tags: pgrep

```bsh
RUNNING_APPS=$(pgrep -f "somePattern")
echo $?

#results in
1
```

How can I make my command pass with exit code 0?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Why are you checking the exit status of the command?

Comment: I've got script with `set -e` flag which fails after this command. Echo is added just to illustrate behavior.

Comment: Please ***edit*** your question to add this then. And give us enough context so we can offer an alternative: this is how `pgrep` behaves so if you _must_ use `set -e`, then you cannot use `prep` like this. Make sure to mention what operating system you are running.  Also, a point on style: avoid using CAPS for variable names in shell scripts, that is bad practice since global environment variables are capitalized and this can cause variable name collisions with unexpected consequences.

Comment: `pgrep -f whatever || true` should return 0 and not trip the -e action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Arch system, with the `pgrep` from `procps-ng`, I see this in `man pgrep`:

```
EXIT STATUS
       0      One  or  more processes matched the criteria. For
              pkill the process must also  have  been  success‐
              fully signalled.
       1      No  processes  matched  or  none of them could be
              signalled.
       2      Syntax error in the command line.
       3      Fatal error: out of memory etc.
```

So this is just the way it is: `pgrep` will exit with 1 if everything worked fine but there were no processes matching the search string. This means you will need to use a different tool. Perhaps something like Kusalananda suggested in the comments and [ilkkachu posted as an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/603993/22222):

```
running_apps=$(pgrep -f "somePattern" || exit 0)
```

But a better approach, IMO, would be to change your script. And instead of using `set -e`, have it exit manually at the important steps. Then, you can use something like this:

```
running_apps=$(pgrep -fc "somePattern")
if [ "$running_apps" = 0 ]; then
    echo "none found"
else
    echo "$running_apps running apps"
fi
```

Comment: Or just use `pgrep ... || exit 0` in the command substitution. Or don't use `set -e`.

Comment: `pgrep -fc` is just a pseudo-code? I get `invalid option -- 'c'`

Comment: @MarcinKozakiewicz that's why I asked you to tell us your operating system. It looks like you are using a different version of `pgrep`. What OS are you on?

Comment: `... | grep -v grep` returns with an error if there are no lines without `grep` in them. Just go with `|| true` to suppress the error exit.

Comment: @ilkkachu is that ever possible given that the command is part of `ps aux | grep one | grep two`? That said, yes the `|| exit 0` trick is indeed a better approach.

Comment: @terdon, well, if you go `ps aux | grep xterm | grep -v xterm` and there's no `xterm` running on the system, then the first `grep` only matches the line for itself (or not even that), and the second doesn't select (print) anything, so it exits `1`.

Comment: @ilkkachu duh, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With `set -e`, commands that on the left side of the AND (`&&`) or OR (`||`) operators don't cause the shell to exit, so you can suppress the error by adding `|| true`.

So this should output `0` regardless of the processes found (and not exit before outputting it):

```
set -e
RUNNING_APPS=$(pgrep -f "somePattern" || true)
echo $?
```